# Using logical 'or' operator correctly with multiple conditions?

Tags: r

I can't really seems to wrap my head around about how I am using the | operator incorrectly. Because my code seems to work correctly without it, I assume I've not understood correctly what it does. But I wasn't able to find an explanation that helps me get to it.

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
x2 <- c(4,5,6,6,5,4)
df <- data.frame(x1,x2)

#simple test: find out which rows have value 1 for x1 and value 4 for x2 at the same time
which(df$x1 == 1 & df$x2 == 4)
[1] 1

#problem: find out which rows have value 1 for x1 and either value 4 or 6 for x2
which(df$x1 == 1 & df$x2 == 4 | 6)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

here should the return be `[1] 1 4`, but for some reason I just get back all the row indicies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write `df$x1 == 1 & (df$x2 == 4 | df$x2  == 6)`

Currently your expression is evaluated as

`(df$x1 == 1 & df$x2 == 4) | 6`

due to *operator precedence*, which is always true.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
which((df$x1 == 1) & (df$x2 %in% c(4,6)))
```

or

```
which((df$x1 == 1) & ((df$x2 == 4)|(df$x2 == 6)))
```

However the second solution is clearly less elegant, I just added it to show you how to use the logical OR.
I would highly recommend to put logical arguments in parentheses.

Comment: Personally I believe the second way only becomes less elegant with all the superfluous parentheses, but upvoted nonetheless.

Comment: Thanks to both of you! @Bathsheba greatly helped me to understand where it went wrong while you offer a different solution! Thanks, again!